# What is the grammar mistake in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

> - We were hot because we'd run.

I am trying to solve this mistake, but it sounds right. 
This mistake is grammatical. 
[image: the second sentence]

Comment: From what book is this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no grammatical mistake here.  "[We'd](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/we'd)" can stand for "we had", "we would" or "we should".

In this case, it stands for "we had": "We were hot because we had run."

Comment: I took this sentence from a question demanding to find the grammatical mistake. How this could be?

Comment: I edited the question and added a picture relating to my question. Look at it.

Comment: My best guess is that the expected correction might be "...because we'd been running".

Comment: @Bavyan: Looks like the people who wrote the test failed. Their understanding of English is a subset of actual English. #4 can also be correct as well as it stands. Sure, you *could* say "went" there, but "go" works as well, and may even be preferable depending on the context.

Comment: On #4, Cambridge are also recommending "went" ( http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/it-s-time ), but when it was last discussed on ELL there was some support for "go" ( https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38525/its-time-you-to-bed ).  It's also been debated on the English SE ( https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61963/why-do-we-say-its-time-we-ate-and-not-its-time-we-eat ).

Comment: (Interesting to note, "time we go" is used without comment as part of a transcript of BrE native-speaker conversation at http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/language/theenglishwespeak/2013/11/131119_tews_150_bottomless.shtml ... as part of a programme that was intended to help people learn English.)

Comment: @Robusto - Unless I’m missing something, I think Nos. 2, 3, 4, and 5 all seem fine.

Comment: I'm not sure if #5 breaks any grammatical rules, though I think "couldn't" or "can't" would be much more idiomatic. In terms of #3, "If I would have seen" is considered non-standard in BrE... Might be accepted in AmE, though.

Comment: @J.R.: I'd prefer "If I had seen you, I would have stopped," but that's probably a style issue. For #5 I suppose a pedant would argue that *mustn't* mustn't be contracted in cases involving present perfect, but I wouldn't care to make that argument.

Comment: I agree with J.R except for #5. "**mustn't**" does fit well in there although it is grammatically correct. Indeed "**couldn't**" or "**can't**" would be prefered. Assuming that it's a grammar book (probably a poor written one) we shouldn't consider "**It's time we go home**" as correct, most grammar books give "**went**" as the only correct option. "**If I would have seen you, I would**" is also inappropriate. It should be "**If I had seen you, I would**"

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, but I would say: We were hot because we'd been running. (as has been noted by a previous answer, the we'd is a common contraction that native speakers use to express we had). But "had run" seems awkward compared to my version. (past perfect continuous)

see https://www.grammarly.com/blog/verb-conjugation/

Answer (score 0):

> We were hot because we'd run.

The sentence is correct but most English tests and grammar books explain this mistake this way: there should be an action in the progressive aspect preceding the result.

- We were hot because we had been running. - is obviously prefered by tests and grammar books. The reason we were hot was because before that we had been running (this is the reason why we were hot).