# We have to go. It is time we…

Tags: subjunctives

The question from the test:

*We have to go. It is time we… 
– A. Leave, B. Are leaving, C. Left, D. Must leave.*

The correct answer is C. Can you please explain why? What grammatical phenomenon is present in this sentence? (I thought that this sentence should include a subjunctive and so I chose the answer A.)

Comment: I have asked the same question before.Hopefully it helps http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38525/all-right-johhny-its-time-you-to-bed

Comment: ouch. That's one of those ones I know the answer instinctively, but cannot explain. As a Northern Brit I would have said "Went" ;) if there had been no multiple-choice, but presumably would have gone for the past tense reflexively.

Comment: IMO it's best to avoid this structure. *sigh* That ain't possible in exams.

Comment: As a side note I don't think any native speaker would bat an eye at any of these in typical conversation.

Comment: [one interesting related question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37796/what-kind-of-grammatical-structure-is-its-time-we-stopped-talking)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["It's time ... 'verb'/'verb-ed' ..."](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2798/its-time-verb-verb-ed)

Answer (score 4):

As far as my memory helps, this structure is used when we want to indicate that **something needed to be done** a while ago and we're a bit **late**. 
Your hunch about the phrase after "we" being a subjunctive is correct. And, you *can* use both present and past tense. However, the present tense might give the audience a "shouting" connotation and thus, isn't frequent.

To be more precise, it's colloquial to have a "high" after "is":

> It's high time I changed those socks!

Comment: One [BBC page says that we use the non-past-tense (plain) verb form here only with infinitive clause constructions](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv347.shtml) - " we can use the construction **it's time to** or **it's time for + object + to** as alternatives to the unreal use of past forms to express this idea" - so - "It's time **for us to leave**"

Comment: "Only" seems a bit, you know, not "buyable". Nothing is impossible in a language as wide as English! Though I completely agree with you in the part that it's best to substitute such structure with infinitives.

Comment: Well, maybe there are other ways, the BBC page is not a CGEL (0: I wonder if it's called "subjunctive" in CGEL though.

Comment: Let's go checking.

Comment: *high* is an intensifier that indicates that the lateness is more extreme.  It can be used both ways (with and without *high*) depending on the amount of lateness the speaker wishes to indicate.  I probably use it more without than with.

Comment: [Here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37796/what-kind-of-grammatical-structure-is-its-time-we-stopped-talking) Tunny provides arguments based on CGEL and on Quirk et al. for not calling such constructions "subjunctive".

Answer (score 3):

> Can you please explain why?

There's an interesting afterthought in a Language Log post titled *"[It's time](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1324)":*

> Some of the comments below ask about why the preterite would be used, and others correctly identify the reason: the preterite tense in English is often used for what is called "*modal remoteness*" — it takes us away from claiming something about the actual world.
>   *If she **knows** where I am right now* is about whether she knows in this world; *if she **knew** where I am right now* is about what it would be like in an alternate world, unlike this one, a world in which she does know.

P.S. "preterite" - past tense form of the verb

Comment: Instead of calling this past tense "past tense of modal remoteness" one should simply say it is past subjunctive. And "It's time we went* (went* means past subjunctive) actually means "It would be time we went". Why the formula is twisted and we say "it's time" (present tense) is another question.

Comment: While the CaGEL is superb, their description of *modal-remoteness* is shockingly poor :( Boo to modal remoteness!

Comment: @Araucaria - I'm not enough of a boffin to root for either of the two concepts with vigour. So far, these are only labels to me. We have a saying "you can label me a kettle if you like to, just don't put me in the oven" (хоть горшком назови, только в печку не ставь). But I like unified terminology. Maybe it's time I read some Quirk and CGEL on the issue. (0:

Answer (score 2):

A and C are both correct.  Letter A uses the present subjunctive and letter C uses the past subjunctive.  It really is a matter of choice in English.  Here are two examples:

"It's time I be made a partner."
"It's time I were made a partner."

Both of these mean the same thing.  I know your ESL teacher wants the past subjunctive "left" used above and not the present subjunctive "leave", so he might frown on my first example; however, both are correct in my examples and both A and C are correct in your situation, whether your ESL teacher "believe" it or not (present subjunctive).  There are a few times in English wherein the present and past subjunctive forms can be used interchangeably; this is one of them.  The second example using "were" or your example using "left" may give off a hint that it is more unlikely to happen than it would be if the present subjunctive were used therein, but it really is preference.

Other examples of present and past subjunctive interchangeability:
"I would rather he be in agreement."
"I would rather he were in agreement."

Answer (score 1):

I believe that we can find this pattern (or structure), *It's time*, in most grammar books. Here is what *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan writes about it:

> **306 it's time**
>   **1 followed by infinitive**
>   ​　　[...]
>   **2 followed by past tense with present meaning**
>   ​　　*It's time* can also be followed by a subject with a past tense verb. The meaning is present.
>   ​　　***It's time she went*** to bed.
>   ​　　***It's time you washed*** those trousers.
>   ​　　*I'm getting tired. **It's time we went** home.*
>   The expression *It's high time ...* is often used in this structure in British English, to say that something is urgent.
>   ​　　***It's high time you got*** a job.

I hope this is helpful.