# Choosing options in "The company is not doing well-isn't it time you sell/sold/selling off your shares in it?"

Tags: tense, phrasal-verbs, subjunctives

> Choose the option which expresses the sentence in the best manner:
>
> The company is not doing well-isn't it time you **sell/sold/selling** off your shares in it?

From my point of view, **sell** is the best option as the sentence is of simple present tense. Using the option **sold** will make it in past tense. Please suggest your answers.

Comment: I posted an entry in a grammar book for this pattern ("It's time ...") once: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/49166/3281.

Comment: I love how the first comment on this question is a link to someone asking a similar question earlier, and the first comment on *that* question is a link to a third, also similar, question, the first comment on which is a link to yet another question (this time, not on ELL) about the same thing. That fourth question is marked as a duplicate in English SE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [We have to go. It is time we…](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49147/we-have-to-go-it-is-time-we)

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/49147/. This question is asking about "ISN"T it time" not "IS it time". The negative could be different, and none of the answers in the proposed duplicate are particularly helpful for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Sold is absolutely right in place of sell.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Can you explain why this is the case?